# What am i doing wrong with this update from select

Tags: mysql

I have been triying to make an update from a select the console keeps showing an error message

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from
  (
    Select
      a.id_activity as stat
      , a.date_reg as l_clock
  ' at line 5*

I would appreciate some help with it.

```
update user_stat set
   clock_stat = a.stat
 , datetime_lclock = a.l_clock
 , date_fclock = a.f_clock
from
 (
Select
  a.id_activity as stat
  , a.date_reg as l_clock
  , date(c.date_reg) as f_clock
from log_activity a
  inner join
    (
      select
        max(id_reg) as last_Act,
        min(id_reg) as first_Act
      from log_activity
        where uid = 1
    )b on a.id_reg = b.last_Act
  left join log_activity c on c.id_reg = b.first_Act
)a
where uid = 1;
```

Comment: It might help to include the error message in your question

Comment: Post error message to help others figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set value later, so the general syntax is some like :

```
   UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]

update user_stat 
join
(
  Select
  a.id_activity as stat
  , a.date_reg as l_clock
  , date(c.date_reg) as f_clock
  from log_activity 
 ) a
  inner join
  (     select
        max(id_reg) as last_Act,
        min(id_reg) as first_Act
       from log_activity where uid = 1
    )b on a.id_reg = b.last_Act
  left join log_activity c on c.id_reg = b.first_Act
set
   clock_stat = a.stat
 , datetime_lclock = a.l_clock
 , date_fclock = a.f_clock
```

Comment: The error is still present, it says that is near the from (select .... and when i run the script without the update it works perfectly fine

Comment: I've modified it -- you can check now

Comment: Nevermind, I used the format as u sugested and I changed the from to a join and now its working, thanks